# How to integrate and use ionicons in android project from android studio?

Tags: android, ionicons

I am looking for some sample code for integrating the ionicons to my android project .

Comment: I dont know if you can do that. if you are looking for good Icons check here https://materialdesignicons.com/

Comment: @Tasos Thanks ...appreciate it

Comment: https://github.com/manuel-zulian/ionicons-for-android